# WCF RIA over Net.TCP binding?

Tags: wcf-ria-services, nettcpbinding

I am trying to improve the performance of a Silverlight 4 WCF RIA application.  As it's for intranet use only, I figured switching from the default binary HTTP binding to the Net.TCP binding might improve performance a bit.

However, I am having a hard time just getting a simple proof of concept application running.  I have:

- switched the proof of conecpt app from Cassini to IIS (7)
- added the appropriate bindings and enabled protocols on IIS
- added a clientaccesspolicy.xml file to my IIS root

Now, when I create a context like so:

```
var context = new DomainService1(
new Uri(
    "net.tcp://localhost:4502/BusinessApplication/BusinessApplication2.Web/ClientBin/BusinessApplication2-Web-DomainService1.svc"));
```

... I get the following error:

```
The provided URI scheme 'net.tcp' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via
```

Now I'm stumped.  As far as I can tell, the problem is that the client being created by the auto-generated WCF RIA code needs to be told that it's to use a Net.TCP endpoint, but I'm unsure how to do that.

I've found plenty of blog posts explaining how to get WCF services going over Net.TCP, but I haven't found a single one talking about WCF RIA, and I can't find any offical documentation either.  All of those explanations involve changes to the web.config file that seem unsuited to a WCF RIA app.

Could some one please either explain to me how to get this configured, or point me at some documentation?

Comment: So far it doesn't look possible: "... RIA Services doesn't support changing (at least, not according to a MS post on a different thread) the DomainContext's binding type." on http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/149151/332402.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF RIA Services depends on HttpContext which is not available with Net.TCP binding.

As for perf issues, could you elaborate a bit further? What is the bottleneck query/operation? What is the size of data (entity size x entity count)? What is the delta between your perf requirements and current perf?

Perhaps there are other ways that don't involve Net.TCP?

Thanks.

Dinesh

(WCF RIA Services Program Manager)

Comment: Dinesh, thanks for the reply. In ~600 characters: we're fetching points for a chart from the server, then calling the server to perform statistical operations multiple times, each time fetching a new set of points.  This replaces a VBA legacy app that has to perform near-instantly because of the number of statistical operations requested in real time.  30ms latency has proved acceptable in prototype tests.  We're fetching between 30 - 100 entities after each operation, totaling ~12kB according to Fiddler. Current round trip is > 100ms.

Comment: Oh and in case you're wondering, we weren't aware of the absolute performance requirements _before_ we started down the WS architecture route.  In hindsight, we should have produced prototypes of varying performance _first_ thereby determining some hard numbers for required performance, and incorporating those (as automated performance tests?) from the outset.