# What protocols do .NET Ria Services support?

Tags: wcf-ria-services

.NET RIA Services work with an HTTP binding. What about TCP or named pipes?

Answer (score 1):

WCF Named pipes don't work outside of a single machine so they don't count in the case of Rich Internet Applications. Not sure about net.tcp

Answer (score 0):

> Net.Tcp does work as far as I know. – the_drow

No, according to it's program manager, Dinesh Kulkarni it's impossible.  [WCF RIA over Net.TCP binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498530/wcf-ria-over-net-tcp-binding)